# Use of a constant inside of a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

My code is :

```
    Dim c3 As MySqlCommand
    Dim q3 As String = "SELECT        date
        FROM            `river-derwent-keswick-portinscale`
     WHERE(`date` = Input)"
    c3 = New MySqlCommand(q3, conn)
    'c3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Userinput.Text)
    'Userinput.Text Is a textbox 
    ' If a field if found where the date matches the userinput
    ' Output value to textbox
    Dim DR3 As MySqlDataReader = c3.ExecuteReader()
    If DR3.Read Then
        Datetxt.Text = DR3.GetValue(0)
    End If
    DR3.Close()
```

This uses a preset constant of a global variable set inside of another form which is Input, where input = textbox1.text. This means a user would input a value into textbox1.text then that value is set as Input. Can someone help me in how to use this constant to query with a Where statement.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it in the commented code. Modify the query to accept a date argument:

```
SELECT  date
FROM   `river-derwent-keswick-portinscale`
WHERE(`date` = @date_param)
```

Then add parameter to the command

```
c3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_param", Userinput.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim c3 As MySqlCommand
Dim q3 As String = "SELECT date FROM `river-derwent-keswick-portinscale` WHERE(`date` = @Date)"
c3 = New MySqlCommand(q3, conn)
c3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Userinput.Text)
'Userinput.Text Is a textbox 
' If a field if found where the date matches the userinput
' Output value to textbox
Dim DR3 As MySqlDataReader = c3.ExecuteReader()
If DR3.Read Then
    Datetxt.Text = DR3.GetValue(0)
End If
DR3.Close()
```